# Find Last Field in Row and Subtract Previous

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that keeps track of word count in various reports. It has a list of projects, a date, and a word count for each date.

Basically:

```
Title    | Date        | Words | Date       | Words | Date       | Words
Report 1 | 07/20/2015  | 100   | 07/21/2015 |150    | 07/23/2015 | 140
Report 2 | 07/20/2015  | 200   | 07/24/2015 |300    |            | 
Report 3 | 07/20/2015  | 10    | 07/23/2015 |100    | 07/24/2015 | 160
```

I have another sheet that keeps track of words written for each day.
Ex:

```
Date       | Words
07/20/2015 | 310
07/21/2015 | 50
07/22/2015 | 0
07/23/2015 | 80
07/24/2015 | 160
```

Right now, I'm updating the second sheet manually. What I want the sheet to do is to find the dates that match column A of sheet 2 for each project, subtract it from the word count of the previous record, and add them together for each day.

I tried doing it using VLookup, but I don't think that's going to work. I know it's probably going to be some convoluted combination of formulas but I'm having a hard time finding a place to start. Any suggestions for how I should tackle this?

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your first sheet in more details? is it supposed to grow in both directions indefinitely?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. It'll probably be impractical after a while, but for now, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SUMIF` function. Your example would be like this:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!B2:B4, Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!C2:C4) + SUMIF(Sheet1!D2:D4, Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!E2:E4) + SUMIF(Sheet1!F2:F4, Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!G2:G4)
```

More about this function on [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-CA/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do that, but you have to predefine a limited range for your data (You CAN make that very very large).

Suppose you define the range to be `Sheet1!A1:ZZ99999`. What you do is use a `SUMIF` with the range being all the rows, and all the columns except the LAST one (so `A1:ZY99999`), the criteria is your date (`A2`, `A3` and so on in `Sheet2`), and the sum range is all the rows and all the columns except the FIRST one (so `B1:ZZ99999`). Since the ranges are unaligned, the contents of each cell determines whether the cell next to it is included in the summation. From that you subtract the value from the cell above.

The formula is `=SUMIF(Sheet1!A1:ZY99999, A3, Sheet1!B1:ZZ99999)-B3`.